# Why is it called “quadratic” voting?

Tags: dapps, dao, voting

What’s “quadratic” about it? Do the votes somehow exhibit “multiplicative” behavior, relative to one another (since each person must subdivide their votes, so the final tally is more like ratios or proportional voting)?

Comment: Julius H, please accept my answer if it was informative for you :)

Answer (score 4):

Classic collective decision making (aka a "majority voting system") is **oftenTimes** vulnerable to a phenomenon of the *"tyranny of the majority"*, hence the 2nd name.

Contrary to that, the **quadratic voting mechanism** (QV) was invented to solve that problem in the following way:

*Consider for instance a situation when a minority cares more about a particular public good than the majority. They are allowed to influence the outcome by casting an unlimited amount of votes (contrary to only 1 vote / person in the traditional majority system).*

---

**The main difference here is that the price of a vote will quadratically increase, based on how many votes an individual has already casted.**

---

Code example:

```
    pragma solidity >=0.4.25 <0.6.0;
    
    import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";
    import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol";
    import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/access/roles/MinterRole.sol";
    
    /**
     * @title QVVoting
     * @dev the manager for proposals / votes
     */
    contract QVVoting is Ownable, MinterRole {
        using SafeMath for uint256;
    
        uint256 private _totalSupply;
        string public symbol;
        string public name;
        mapping(address => uint256) private _balances;
    
        event VoteCasted(address voter, uint ProposalID, uint256 weight);
    
        event ProposalCreated(
            address creator,
            uint256 ProposalID,
            string description,
            uint votingTimeInHours
        );
    
        enum ProposalStatus {IN_PROGRESS, TALLY, ENDED}
    
        struct Proposal {
            address creator;
            ProposalStatus status;
            uint256 yesVotes;
            uint256 noVotes;
            string description;
            address[] voters;
            uint expirationTime;
            mapping(address => Voter) voterInfo;
        }
    
        struct Voter {
            bool hasVoted;
            bool vote;
            uint256 weight;
        }
    
        mapping(uint256 => Proposal) public Proposals;
        uint public ProposalCount;
    
        constructor() public {
            symbol = "QVV";
            name = "QV Voting";
        }
    
        /**
        * @dev Creates a new proposal.
        * @param _description the text of the proposal
        * @param _voteExpirationTime expiration time in minutes
        */
        function createProposal(
            string calldata _description,
            uint _voteExpirationTime
        ) external onlyOwner returns (uint) {
            require(_voteExpirationTime > 0, "The voting period cannot be 0");
            ProposalCount++;
    
            Proposal storage curProposal = Proposals[ProposalCount];
            curProposal.creator = msg.sender;
            curProposal.status = ProposalStatus.IN_PROGRESS;
            curProposal.expirationTime = now + 60 * _voteExpirationTime * 1 seconds;
            curProposal.description = _description;
    
            emit ProposalCreated(
                msg.sender,
                ProposalCount,
                _description,
                _voteExpirationTime
            );
            return ProposalCount;
        }
    
        /**
        * @dev sets a proposal to TALLY.
        * @param _ProposalID the proposal id
        */
        function setProposalToTally(uint _ProposalID)
            external
            validProposal(_ProposalID)
            onlyOwner
        {
            require(
                Proposals[_ProposalID].status == ProposalStatus.IN_PROGRESS,
                "Vote is not in progress"
            );
            require(
                now >= getProposalExpirationTime(_ProposalID),
                "voting period has not expired"
            );
            Proposals[_ProposalID].status = ProposalStatus.TALLY;
        }
    
        /**
        * @dev sets a proposal to ENDED.
        * @param _ProposalID the proposal id
        */
        function setProposalToEnded(uint _ProposalID)
            external
            validProposal(_ProposalID)
            onlyOwner
        {
            require(
                Proposals[_ProposalID].status == ProposalStatus.TALLY,
                "Proposal should be in tally"
            );
            require(
                now >= getProposalExpirationTime(_ProposalID),
                "voting period has not expired"
            );
            Proposals[_ProposalID].status = ProposalStatus.ENDED;
        }
    
        /**
        * @dev returns the status of a proposal
        * @param _ProposalID the proposal id
        */
        function getProposalStatus(uint _ProposalID)
            public
            view
            validProposal(_ProposalID)
            returns (ProposalStatus)
        {
            return Proposals[_ProposalID].status;
        }
    
        /**
        * @dev returns a proposal expiration time
        * @param _ProposalID the proposal id
        */
        function getProposalExpirationTime(uint _ProposalID)
            public
            view
            validProposal(_ProposalID)
            returns (uint)
        {
            return Proposals[_ProposalID].expirationTime;
        }
    
        /**
        * @dev counts the votes for a proposal. Returns (yeays, nays)
        * @param _ProposalID the proposal id
        */
        function countVotes(uint256 _ProposalID) public view returns (uint, uint) {
            uint yesVotes = 0;
            uint noVotes = 0;
    
            address[] memory voters = Proposals[_ProposalID].voters;
            for (uint i = 0; i < voters.length; i++) {
                address voter = voters[i];
                bool vote = Proposals[_ProposalID].voterInfo[voter].vote;
                uint256 weight = Proposals[_ProposalID].voterInfo[voter].weight;
                if (vote == true) {
                    yesVotes += weight;
                } else {
                    noVotes += weight;
                }
            }
    
            return (yesVotes, noVotes);
    
        }
    
        /**
        * @dev casts a vote.
        * @param _ProposalID the proposal id
        * @param numTokens number of voice credits
        * @param _vote true for yes, false for no
        */
        function castVote(uint _ProposalID, uint numTokens, bool _vote)
            external
            validProposal(_ProposalID)
        {
            require(
                getProposalStatus(_ProposalID) == ProposalStatus.IN_PROGRESS,
                "proposal has expired."
            );
            require(
                !userHasVoted(_ProposalID, msg.sender),
                "user already voted on this proposal"
            );
            require(
                getProposalExpirationTime(_ProposalID) > now,
                "for this proposal, the voting time expired"
            );
    
            _balances[msg.sender] = _balances[msg.sender].sub(numTokens);
    
            uint256 weight = sqrt(numTokens); // QV Vote
    
            Proposal storage curproposal = Proposals[_ProposalID];
    
            curproposal.voterInfo[msg.sender] = Voter({
                hasVoted: true,
                vote: _vote,
                weight: weight
            });
    
            curproposal.voters.push(msg.sender);
    
            emit VoteCasted(msg.sender, _ProposalID, weight);
        }
    
        /**
        * @dev checks if a user has voted
        * @param _ProposalID the proposal id
        * @param _user the address of a voter
        */
        function userHasVoted(uint _ProposalID, address _user)
            internal
            view
            validProposal(_ProposalID)
            returns (bool)
        {
            return (Proposals[_ProposalID].voterInfo[_user].hasVoted);
        }
    
        /**
        * @dev checks if a proposal id is valid
        * @param _ProposalID the proposal id
        */
        modifier validProposal(uint _ProposalID) {
            require(
                _ProposalID > 0 && _ProposalID <= ProposalCount,
                "Not a valid Proposal Id"
            );
            _;
        }
    
        /**
        * @dev returns the square root (in int) of a number
        * @param x the number (int)
        */
        function sqrt(uint x) internal pure returns (uint y) {
            uint z = (x + 1) / 2;
            y = x;
            while (z < y) {
                y = z;
                z = (x / z + z) / 2;
            }
        }
    
        /**
        * @dev minting more tokens for an account
        */
        function mint(address account, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
            require(account != address(0), " mint to the zero address");
            _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(amount);
            _balances[account] = _balances[account].add(amount);
        }
    
        /**
        * @dev returns the balance of an account
        */
        function balanceOf(address account) public view returns (uint256) {
            return _balances[account];
        }
    
    }
```